# MVC3 - Reading GET Variables Into Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller action /Responses/Insert and want to be able to GET variables from URL and save them to my database.

The URL will look like this:

```
/Responses/Insert?pass=blah&msisdn=blah&sender=blah&message=blah&dca=blah&msg_id=blahsource_id=blah
```

Here is my model:

```
public class Response
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public string msisdn { get; set; }
    public string sender { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string dca { get; set; }
    public string msg_id { get; set; }
    public string source_id { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone offer advice on how to code my controller action?

```
//
// GET: /Response/Insert

public ActionResult Insert()
{
    return View();
}
```

Thanks very much!

Paul

**EDIT 1 - SOLVED (Thanks LukLed)**

```
    public ActionResult Insert(Response response)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            responseRepository.InsertOrUpdate(response);
            responseRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should consider using POST instead of GET when you are modifying data.  I think the main reason is that browsers and proxies may cache the request, but it makes more sense to use the proper HTTP verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Insert(Response response)
{
    return View();
}
```

Model binder will handle turning `GET` values into `Response` object.

Comment: that simple? do you not have to somehow state to GET the data from the URL?

Comment: @Paul Brown: Yes, that simple. If properties are named the same as `GET` params, that should work.

Comment: On going to the URL it returns the view but no data inserted :( any further ideas?

Comment: @Paul Brown: What do you mean by no data inserted? If you have `msisdn` `GET` param and `Response` class has `msisdn` property, this has to work.